# Calling web service using JavaScript

Tags: webservices

I am using wrapper class to fetch the consumer object values and passed into Data table,

In that I am using consumer code and consumer name are the two text boxes.

Once I am enter the Consumer code,  I need to make a Webservice call via javascript(not in apex code) and fetch the customer name from external webservice.

How to do that?

Plese share the sample code also if possible.

Comment: Any reason why you dont want to make a call through apex class?

Comment: If you're not using Apex, just do it the same way you would make any other webservice or ajax call from javascript -- it doesn't really matter that you're using Salesforce at that point.

Comment: Also, please include the **relevant lines** of your Visualforce page and/or html to help us understand your need and how we could help answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to utilize the AJAX toolkit:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

It could look like this, if your webservice method return a string:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js" />

<script>
var custName = "" + sforce.apex.execute("WebServiceClass","yourMethod", 
                                       {param1:"1234", 
                                        param2:"true"}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can use Javascript remoting to call a method in the controller, from the controller method call your webservice and return the desired value.

For more details on apex remoting please go through the following link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm